# Too many Oracle connections open

Tags: c#, .net-core, oracle11g, database-connection, oracle.manageddataaccess

I have a .NET Core web api on IIS running and I'm using oracle as database and I do connect to it like this.

```
using(OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    //some other code here
    con.Open();
}
```

I'm not using EF or so. I (de)serialze the data from the reader directly into a json or xml string.

I have a small batch file to test the api. The batch sends a request using curl every second and when I run the batch file 5 times, to simulate a little bit of traffic, (I know there are some tools for that, but thats not the problem) the api has open 7 connections to the database. Why are 7 db connections open, how to handle it, so that a maximum of 2 or 3 simultaneously are open, even if a request has to wait?

I do not want to "just make it work", I want it to work the right way. Because of that, I want to now, is "connection pooling" the keyword here? Especially the max pool size, could I just set it to 3, or did I forget something to set up, or something?

Comment: Why would you want a request to wait for a database connection to become available? Considering that Oracle.ManagedDataAccess does not do true async, your service's threads will be stalled waiting for either `Open` *or* `OpenAsync` to return instead of yielding the thread to another request. This sounds like a performance nightmare.

Comment: @Madreflection yeah, its not my idea, but its my job now to reduce the connections.

Comment: It should also be your job to explain to them why this is a horrible idea.

Comment: yeah, but I cant explain that to my boss developer :D

Comment: Do your own connection *object* pooling, so that you never have more than 3 connection objects available, and *maybe* it won't open any new connections. Then wait for the system to come grinding to a halt. Maybe then they'll listen.

Comment: Building in a bottleneck is tricky when you have no direct access to the system that seeks to prevent bottlenecks.